# How to check if Swift URL is directory

Tags: ios, swift, macos

How can I check if a Swift URL represents a file or a directory?

There is a `hasDirectoryPath` attribute on the URL object, but there doesn't seem to be any 'intelligence' behind it.
It just reflects the `isDirectory` value passed to the URL.

**code:**

```
  let URL1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
  print(URL1.hasDirectoryPath)
  let URL2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath, isDirectory: true)
  print(URL2.hasDirectoryPath)
```

**output:**

```
  false
  true
```

Comment: There's also this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410277-fileexists

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The name says it all "hasDirectoryPath". It doesn't state that the URL is a directory and it exists. It says that it has a directory path. To make sure that the URL is a directory you can get URL ResourceKey [isDirectoryKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/1410514-isdirectorykey):

```
extension URL {
    var isDirectory: Bool {
       (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]))?.isDirectory == true
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the hasDirectoryPath then exactly? The explanation on the Swift documentation says: `A Boolean that is true if the URL path represents a directory.` Which I interpreted as being: the path is a directory.

Comment: Oh, wait I think I get it, is "hasDirectoryPath" perhaps to show the difference between a path on the filesystem an an http url?

Comment: In order for me to get this to work I had to add ```return``` in front of the “try“ call.  I'm using swift 5.5.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense unless you have added some code above that single line which is being returned

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add a return statement in some cases. Especially if the code in the block is a one liner. Just write it and the compiler knows that that is the return value.

Comment: "It doesn't state that the URL is a directory and it exists" that doesn't seem to be true according to my tests. Calling `URL(fileURLWithPath: path).hasDirectoryPath` with a path that points to an existing directory returns `true`, calling it with a path that points to a regular or non-existing file returns `false`.

Comment: @YourMJK I don't think you understood my point try `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("whatever", isDirectory: true).hasDirectoryPath` will always return `true` regardless of the existence of that subdirectory.

Comment: @LeoDabus I wanted to correct this since you seemed to agree with OP that "there doesn't seem to be any 'intelligence' behind it. It just reflects the `isDirectory` value" which isn't true. I can't replicate OP's output, `URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath).hasDirectoryPath` returns `true` for me on macOS, both in a Playground and CLI program.

Comment: @YourMJK Sorry I still don't understand your point. Again you can use that property to check if the url represents a directory but there is no guarantee that it has been already created. Of course you can create a file using that same url `try! Data("Text".utf8).write(to: subdirectoryURL)` and `hasDirectoryPath` will continue returning `true` after that. If you use the extension above would return `false`

Comment: @LeoDabus See my new answer. You are right, there is no guarantee but `hasDirectoryPath` will be true if at the time you created an `URL` with `URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` there existed a directory at `path`

Answer (score 7):

I just simplified and upgrade what Leo answered with better return.

**Info:** In my answer you are getting 3 possible results, **true** it means the url is a directory, **false** it means it is not a directory and it is a file! **nil** means it is not a Dir or file, because we can gave a dummy url or a website to url, in this case you would return nil and a ***bonus*** information from Swift about why the return is **nil** and helps you solve the issue in case, to let you know what is the situation of url. With the current accepted answer a dummy url or an invalid url could be miss understood as a file for some developers.

```
extension URL {
    var isDirectory: Bool? {

        do {
            return (try resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the misunderstanding lies in the fact that `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` and `URL(fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:)` are two different constructors, there is not a default value of `false` for `isDirectory`.

If `path` doesn't have a trailing slash, **calling just `URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` will in fact check if a directory exists at the path.**
We can confirm this by checking [the implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/NSURL.swift#L228-L243):

```
public init(fileURLWithPath path: String) {
    let thePath: String = _standardizedPath(path)

    var isDir: ObjCBool = false
    if validPathSeps.contains(where: { thePath.hasSuffix(String($0)) }) {
        isDir = true
    } else {
#if !os(WASI)
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: &isDir) {
                isDir = false
            }
#endif
    }
    super.init()
    _CFURLInitWithFileSystemPathRelativeToBase(_cfObject, thePath._cfObject, kCFURLPlatformPathStyle, isDir.boolValue, nil)
}
```

If `path` *does* have a "/" at the end, `hasDirectoryPath` will always be true.

That means you must have made a mistake because I can't reproduce the output from your question.
`URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath).hasDirectoryPath`
returns `true` for me on macOS.

---

But if you want to check for certain whether there *currently* exists a directory at the path of a `URL`, you should check it like this:

```
var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) && isDirectory.boolValue else {
    // url is an existing directory
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For some reason code of Leo Dabus works, BUT NOT ALWAYS(!!!!!!!!!). Be careful!

## So better to use THIS CODE:

```
extension URL {
    //IMPORTANT: this code return false even if file or directory does not exist(!!!)
    var isDirectory: Bool {
       return hasDirectoryPath
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you explained under what conditions the other answer doesn't work. And what's the point of this extension? Why not simply call `hasDirectoryPath` directly if that is actually a valid test that the given URL represents an existing file path that is a directory?

Answer (score -7):

Its check directory and return true or false

```
extension URL    {
    func checkFileExist() -> Bool {
        let path = self.path
        if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path))   {
            print("URL AVAILABLE")
            return true
        }else        {
            print("URL NOT AVAILABLE")
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Uses:**

```
if fileName.checkFileExist{
  // Here, do something
}
```